# Fragment prev deprecated how to change this code Android studio

Tags: java, android, fragment, deprecated

This code I use in my app. It shows that fragment `prev=getFragmentManager()` is deprecated. How solve this problem?

`@OnClick(R.id.am_fab_search)`

```
void searchClicked() {
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    Fragment prev = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("dialog");
    if (prev != null) {
        return;
    }
    ft.addToBackStack(null);

    SearchDialogFragment searchDialog =
            SearchDialogFragment.newInstance(currentSearchItem != null,
                    currentSearchItem);
    searchDialog.show(ft, "dialog");
}
```

Comment: Please, include code in the form of formatted text, not as image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment` instead of `android.app.Fragment`.  See the [documentation here](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment) for more info, and [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment) for how to add the library.

Comment: Thank you but it didn't work for me .What are other possible solutions ?

Comment: As the documentation says, you need to call `getSupportFragmentManager()` when using the androidx Fragment library

Comment: Could you please tell me how to do that ?

Comment: Where your code says `getFragmentManager()`, change it to `getSupportFragmentManager()`

Comment: Thank you it worked but now this code doesnt function like before :(

Comment: @OnClick(R.id.am_fab_search)
    void searchClicked() {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        android.support.v4.app.Fragment prev = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("dialog");
        if (prev != null) {
            return;
        }
        ft.addToBackStack(null);

        SearchDialogFragment searchDialog =
                SearchDialogFragment.newInstance(currentSearchItem != null,
                        currentSearchItem);
        searchDialog.show(ft, "dialog");
    }

Comment: `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` indicates that you are not using the androidx fragment library - you should migrate to that to get the latest features and bugfixes.  I'm not sure if that will help with your code functioning differently - you probably should address that as a separate question.  If this helped with your problem, feel free to accept the answer to help others who come across it :-)